# raspberry pi's linux agent unable to connect cumulocity platform

Tags: linux, iot, raspberry-pi3, cumulocity

I am trying to connect my cumulocity-rpi-agent to cumulocity so that I can have two options either accept or cancel. But right now I am unable to to see accpet option for my device.

```
1) wget http://resources.cumulocity.com/examples/cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
2) sudo dpkg -i cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
```

I have executed these commands 
then i have hit `dpkg --list` list command and `cumulocity-rpi-agent` now visible in result.
But my problem begins after above steps and can't proceed to next (When agent is installed, you should update the configuration file which is usually located at "./cfg/cumulocity-config.properties" and fill the host property value. Open Cumulocity in a web browser and go to the "Registration" page. Enter the serial number that you wrote down in the previous step and click "Register Device".) 
I cant find `./cfg/cumulocity-config.properties` these directory and file after installation

I refereed and followed https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/devices/raspberry-pi/ this link

I hit the `sudo rebbot` to get the accept button on cumulocity platform to accept device

Comment: find . -name "cumulocity-config.properties" See if the file is located somewhere else in the directory structure.

Comment: Can you check /usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent/cfg/cumulocity.properties, please?

Answer (score 1):

I found this file on `/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent/cfg` on this location